# How to centered vis.js network in a modal?

Tags: javascript, vis.js

Currently I have a problem on how to centered a network while opening a modal using vis.js. I have no issue if not using modal, the network is centered perfectly. I just replicate the same code HTML and JS but different result if using modal.

This is view if using modal.

[image]

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.10.0/vis.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.10.0/vis.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal fade" id="myId" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Add Service</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="addServiceTopo">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div id="mynetwork" style="height:400px;width:100%;"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var nodes = new vis.DataSet([
        { id: 1, label: "Node 1" },
        { id: 2, label: "Node 2" },
        { id: 3, label: "Node 3" },
        { id: 4, label: "Node 4" },
        { id: 5, label: "Node 5" }
    ]);
    var edges = new vis.DataSet([
        { from: 1, to: 3 },
        { from: 1, to: 2 },
        { from: 2, to: 4 },
        { from: 2, to: 5 },
        { from: 3, to: 4 }
    ]);
    var container = document.getElementById("mynetwork");
    var data = {
        nodes: nodes,
        edges: edges
    };
    var options = {};
    var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Anyone can give better answer?

Comment: I found this searching for a solution to the same issue 3 years on from this original post. Did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score -1):

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.10.0/vis.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.10.0/vis.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal fade" id="myId" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Add Service</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="addServiceTopo">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div id="mynetwork" style="height:400px;width:100%;"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
  function network_draw(){
      var nodes = new vis.DataSet([
          { id: 1, label: "Node 1" },
          { id: 2, label: "Node 2" },
          { id: 3, label: "Node 3" },
          { id: 4, label: "Node 4" },
          { id: 5, label: "Node 5" }
      ]);
      var edges = new vis.DataSet([
          { from: 1, to: 3 },
          { from: 1, to: 2 },
          { from: 2, to: 4 },
          { from: 2, to: 5 },
          { from: 3, to: 4 }
      ]);
      var container = document.getElementById("mynetwork");
      var data = {
          nodes: nodes,
          edges: edges
      };
      var options = {};
      var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
  };

  $('#myId').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    network_draw();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Please do not simply code dump answers, provide some context on _how_ this answers the question and what the problem was

Comment: The explanation of this answer is that visnetwork won't center the graph correctly if it is **not** visible.
Instead of initializing it in the event 'ready', you should make it in an event that make the graph container visible, like 'shown.bs.modal' in this case.